# dropzone js upload multiple file inconsistent

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

Issue happens when I upload multiple files. Let's say I upload 7 files, some times it only takes 2 - other times all 7 files. I am not expecting any return yet, just using dropzone and move the file to the folder.

I reduced the code so its straight forward:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" 
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    maxFilesize: 25, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        this.on("success", function(file, dataURL) {
            //No return yet, so ignore this
        });
    }
};
```

upload.php

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
if (!file_exists("folder")) {
    mkdir("../somefolder/", 0777, true);
}

$storeFolder = "../somefolder/";  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];         
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually by default dropzone process 2 files on batches.

So if you try to upload 5 images it will send 3 ajax requests(2 files, 2 files, 1 file).

To send all 7 files at one request, you have to set **parallelUploads** option to the desired number - http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-parallelUploads